# Replace Deprecated method hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, deprecated

Session interface method createQuery​(String queryString) deprecated. Why is it deprecated?It is outdated but nothing has been proposed to replace it. Is there a similar method with string HQL for delete operations.

For delete/update/insert operations it works fine, but it is marked deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [javadocs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/QueryProducer.html#createQuery(java.lang.String)) which state

> Deprecated. use createQuery(String, Class),
> createSelectionQuery(java.lang.String) or createMutationQuery(String)
> depending on intention

For insert / update / delete (eg for mutative actions) you should be using `Session.createMutationQuery(String)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `@NamedQuery`?

```java
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
   @NamedQuery(
      name = "person.findByNameLike", 
      query = "from Person where name like :name"
   ),
   @NamedQuery(
      name = "person.deleteByNameLike", 
      query = "delete from Person where name like :name"
   )
})
public class Person {
    @Id
    private long id;

    private String name;
}
```

```
public class PersonDao {
    private final Session session;

    public PersonDao(Session session) { this.session = session; }

    public List<Person> findByNameLike(String name) {
        Query<Person> query = session.createNamedQuery("person.findByNameLike", Person.class);
        query.setParameter("name", "%" + name + "%");
        return query.list();
    }

    public int deleteByNameLike(String name) {
        MutationQuery query = session.createNamedMutationQuery​("person.deleteByNameLike");
        query.setParameter("name", "%" + name + "%");
        return query.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

See https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-named-query

Comment: no, the problem is that the `createNamedQuery(String name,Person.class)` method returns `Person`. And they not work with insert delete/update operations since they have nothing to return.

Comment: For delete / update / insert you can call `Query.executeUpdate()` instead of `Query.list()`. See additions to the answer

Comment: yes, but your method  `createNamedQuery​(String name)` deprecated, that's why I asked the question

Comment: Solved with `Session.createNamedMutationQuery(...)`